# Todo list that allows uploads and review closed tasks

Tags: web-apps, todo

I've been trying out a few todo lists lately and I'm not sure I have found what I'm looking for yet.

My criteria:

- Mobile/Windows/Linux capable
- Can be a free or paid web application.
- Prefer it to be hosted or self hosted so I can centralize my checklists.
- Access history in case I need to review an issue that came up previously
- Hide completed tasks Share lists with spouse (I work with with her also)
- Individual checklists for work/personal/etc
- Attachments - Need to be able to add attachments such as pdfs, markdown files, config files, images, etc.
- Priority Oriented
- Notes on each todo list item

Nice features to have:

- Subtasks
- Google (or any) Calendar integration
- be able to log events with date and time in the individual notes of each item

I'm in the IT field and I was keeping my todo lists in Toodledo. I started having issues with attachments and too many notes so I moved to a local system. I need it accessible from home/work/phone/etc since I use it for personal tasks also.

I know most of these features are covered by a lot of Todo lists out there but I need something a little more involved than a basic todo list. Maybe a different approach? I don't know, maybe you guys have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

I am using [Asana](https://asana.com/).  It is available on multiple platforms, which means it is in the cloud.  It has all the features you are looking for.

I use the free version, which is single user.  For your case there will be a charge, unless you use the same login.  It handles tasks, lists, projects, subtasks etc. You can tag the tasks with dates, priorities and users.  Completed tasks are still viewable.

Comment: ty I'll check it out!